# How to connect to database (Laravel with ddev and MySQL)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ddev

I have a Laravel project where I have to connect to a MySQL db. I deployed the project with ddev, so I´m using docker.
The .env file have this credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=db
DB_PASSWORD=db
```

With this configuration, I can do migrations, and all goes in the right way, but HOW can I see this database? Can I link a DB which is in my local MySQL server? For example, Can I change this host for localhost and set a DB created by me?

I really don´t know why this works, so if somebody helps me, I will be thankfull.

Comment: You can link to any DB host that the app has network access to. Keep in mind that if your app is running in a container, `localhost` is the container and not the host. You'd need to use the [appropriate network address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/283366)

Comment: Regarding the configuration above, `db` is likely another container on the same network / cluster running a MySQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore your database in so many different ways:

- `ddev mysql`
- `ddev launch -p` (or click the link in `ddev describe` to use PhpMyAdmin
- Use the mysql client in either web container or db container

You can export the database to text format with `ddev export-db` or make a binary snapshot with `ddev snapshot`.

There's lots more detail and more options for database browsers at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/database_management/